# store attr style in a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, styles, attr

Is there a way to store style attr in a variable using JS ?

I tried this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c4e9eoqm/)

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: cyan"></div>

var style = 'style="' + $("div").attr('style') + '"';
    alert(style);
```

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve, because this gets the style string correctly e.g `width: 100px; height: 100px; background: cyan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying this on your website exactly as the code appears here?  If so, it's probably returning undefined because you have more than one 'div' present on the page.  Try giving the div in question an ID, and change the JS from $('div') to $('#whateveridyouchose').

Try this code to rule out the image's availability as an issue:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  var style = 'style="' + $("selectorofimage").attr('style') + '"'; alert(style);
});
```

Comment: It's actually an image, the path to element is good. The problem could be that image is not loaded when script runs.

Comment: That'd certainly result in undefined, you could wrap the JS in a document.ready function to rule out that possibility.  To confirm, the JS above will return the styles that are explicitly assigned to the DOM element in question.  With your use-case being an image, I'm wondering if maybe you're trying to get the dimensions of the image itself, rather than the style attrs?  Just wanting to confirm that you're barking up the right tree.

Comment: The style of image contains only positioning and dimensions properties. I wrapped that script in [onAvailable()](https://jsfiddle.net/y20v4p9c/) function and it still returns undefined.

Comment: Edited my answer above, try that code rather than the onAvailable function... assuming the image is in your markup and not being added after page load via AJAX or something.  That should return any styles that are set inline on the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var style = 'style="' + document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('style') + '"';
```

is the pure JavaScript version of your example.

Comment: If put the JS on my website it will show style="undefined"